# Is there a shortcut way to return an array sorted in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

... other than using:
`Array.Copy(originalArray, newArray)`
to make a copy of the original one and then using:
`return Array.Sort (newArray)`
 to get the sorted array -- without changing the original array, of course?

Comment: LINQ has an `OrderBy` extension method that could be what you're looking for.  (I suppose you'd need to call `.ToArray()` if an array is what you need for output, so maybe this isn't much of a shortcut in terms of code length.)

Comment: Wasn't necessarily looking to store output in new array, so thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use LINQ, then convert back to an array:

For example:

```
return array.OrderBy(o => o.Col).ToArray();
```

Comment: Before i accept this as an answer, I'd like to know whether you really meant the assigned array to be the same as the one on which the OrderBy is operated. Also, i suppose we could just return whatevers on the right side of the equals-to, given that I'm not necessarily looking to store the sorted array.

Comment: Yes I think I misread the "Without changing the original array part", I'll remove the assignment part

Comment: Would you mind explaining what `o.Col` refers to? I would have expected just `o` as in the answer of atlaste. Maybe just a copy&paste typo?

Comment: @Johnson this was a while a go but I must have been referring to ordering by a certain item. This would order the array by 'Col'

Answer (score 4):

So 2 operations, (1): order by and (2) copy to new array. I'd say that's something like this:

```
int[] ReturnSorted(int[] input) 
{
    return input.OrderBy((a)=>a).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I like this, but I should have added "... and other than creating a custom method" :)

Comment: @PatrickGomes Obviously you don't need the method; you might just as well use the one-liner...